# What should be the strategy to develop & integrate a package in npm module that also requires react-native linking?

Tags: package, react-native, npm-install, react-native-ios

Hye..

I'm currently trying to start contributing to community but want to understand few basic things.

Question: if we need to develop some wrapper analytics that require to integrate with few third-party package that require native linking (e.g firebase/leanplum). how do we include that inside our module (rather than put as peer dependencies). so, that when end user use our module, basically they just need to do

```
yarn add somepackages && npx pod-install
```

and automatically it will include the third-party packages as well.

I try to find some guidelines but all of it only show the step for integrate with either vanilla js / js packages.

Comment: good question, i leave a link that might help you understanding alternatives and the importance of peerdependency for such cases : https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/870

Comment: @Nostromo it's brief yet cover most of things that I want to know. Thanks!